# Python 3 Beautiful Soup find tag with colon

Tags: python, python-3.x, tags, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this site and get two separate tags. This is what the html looks like.

```
<url>
  <loc>
    http://link.com
  </loc>
  <lastmod>date</lastmode>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <image:image>
   <image:loc>
    https://imagelink.com
   <image:loc>
   <image:title>Item title</image:title>
  <image:image>
</url>
```

the tags I am trying to get are the loc and image:title. The problem I am having is the colon in the title tag. The code I have so far is

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('url'):
    print(item.loc)
    #print image title
```

i have also tried to do just

```
print(item.title)
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: That is xml not html and one node that has a namespace attached not two. where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse it in ["xml" mode](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) instead (requires `lxml` to be installed as well):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<url>
  <loc>
    http://link.com
  </loc>
  <lastmod>date</lastmod>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <image:image>
   <image:loc>
    https://imagelink.com
   </image:loc>
   <image:title>Item title</image:title>
  </image:image>
</url>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'xml')

for item in soup.find_all('url'):
    print(item.title.get_text())
```

Prints `Item title`.

Note that I've applied several fixes to your XML string since it was initially non-well-formed.

Answer (score 0):

I am parsing Confluence XHTML with BeautifulSoup and alecxe's solution did not satisfy me as I really need the `html` mode of BeautifulSoup.

So I've found a hacky solution to use regular expressions:

```py
>>> import re
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> data = """
... <url>
...   <loc>
...     http://link.com
...   </loc>
...   <lastmod>date</lastmod>
...   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
...   <image:image>
...    <image:loc>
...     https://imagelink.com
...    </image:loc>
...    <image:title>Item title</image:title>
...   </image:image>
... </url>"""
>>>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find_all('image:title')  # nope, bs4 won't allow us to do this
[]
>>> soup.find_all(re.compile('image:title'))  # but this works
[<image:title>Item title</image:title>]
```